# Close multiple modal form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using JavaScript and I open multiple modal form on a button click. On a certain modal form I have submit button, so when the data is submitted successfully. I want system should close all the modal form. Please help me in this issue.
I am using `window.showModalDialog()`.

Comment: Please add a fiddler to make your question clear

Comment: Are you using a third party script for the modals or your own?

Comment: showModalDialog is being deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog

Comment: No, I using the javascript's inbuilt function.